# Split the output in PHP

Tags: php, split, explode, preg-split, du

I'm trying to use either split, preg_split, or explode to parse the following data into an array so that I can easily print and modify the data:

```
28782188    /var/opt
```

When I run

`print_r(preg_split('/ /', $input));`

All I get is

```
Array ( [0] => 28782796 /var/opt )
```

Is there a way to make php split with the whitespace that I'm getting from my du calls?

Comment: have you tried `explode(' ',$input);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want

```
preg_split('/\s+/',$input);
```

To split by any white-space character - du seperates with **tabs** (`\t`) if I remember right, although don't quote me on that...

**EDIT** Changed regex to one that works...

Comment: This is the output I got:

Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => )

Comment: Change the regular expression to /\S+/

Comment: @Paul try the updated version (lifted straight off the examples on the [preg_split() manual page](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php))

Comment: Beautiful, works with preg_split('/[\s,]+/',$input);

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Paul note that it will also split by commas, you may want to the remove the comma from the character class... I have just edited above again.

Comment: @Dave, Great! I'll go ahead and remove it as well, but it shouldn't be an issue unless someone ends up with a comma in their path/filename.

Comment: It must be said I don't quite understand why this works. If you read [this page](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) it suggests `\S` should be what you would use to match any whitespace character, but if you actually try it `\s` is the one that works. Odd.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Uhm.. the page you linked to clearly says `\S` matches non-whitespace chars, `\s` matches whitespace chars. You want to split on whitespace, not non-WS. Also, the regex can be simplified: `/\s+/`. The `[]` add no value here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  $value = '28782188 /var/opt';
  $values = array();

  //du might separate size and directory with **multiple** space/tabs
  preg_match_all('/\w*\S[\w\/]*/', $value, $values, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  print_r($values);
  // outputs: Array ( [0] => '28782188', [1] => '/var/opt' )
?>
```

Comment: Output: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => )

Comment: @ Clement, see DaveRandom's post for a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r(explode(' ', $input));` to break input over whitespace.

Comment: Still getting: Array ( [0] => 28792516 /var/opt )

Comment: Try can exploding over '\t' instead

Comment: That didn't work either, DaveRandom found a solution that works though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)...

```
print_r(explode(' ', $input));
```

Comment: That was the first trick I tried. DaveRandom ended up finding a solution.